# Difference between Vuex store WATCH and SUBSCRIBE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

What is the main difference between `watch` and `subscribe` and when I should use one over another? From [Vuex official documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch), it seems both methods are doing the same thing and serving the same purpose, both methods have access to the `state` object.

I am now having a state like below:

```
item: (state: any) => state.item
```

I also have an action to commit a mutation to change the value of `item`, now I would like to know the new value of `item` in some other component, which one I should use? `watch` or `subscribe`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case that you want to do something when the value of `item` changes, using `watch` would be sufficient.

However, if you want to know how `item` is changed specifically, you would want access to the `mutation` object (which includes the `type` of mutation, the `payload`, and so on). In that case, you can use `subscribe`.

One example can be that you mutate `item` in 2 or more mutations and you only want to know the value of `item` when `mutation1` changed it.

Edit: I haven't tried this, but I think using `subscribe` will call your function every time anything in the store is mutated.

Comment: Yeah I suspect the same that `subscribe` will fire for every single mutation thus I am not sure using `subscribe` will cause any side effect. As I know the official documentation doesn't mention about this. Or I missed it?